# Can a <select> be bound to an array by index in Angular.js?

Tags: arrays, angularjs

Say I have this:

```
$scope.items = ["foo", "bar", "baz"];
$scope.index = 1;
```

How do I bind that to a `<select>`?

I tried: `<select ng-model="index" ng-options="i for i in items">` but then a blank option is selected at load time.

This: `<select ng-model="items[index]" ng-options="i for i in items">` seems to work initially but when changing the selection, the value at items[index] is changed, which is obviously not what we want.

My workaround is to map the array to {num, title} pairs but that logic clutters up the controller.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try the following:

```
<select ng-model="index" ng-options="i as name for (i, name) in items">
```

If you check the [ng-options documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:select), you'll see one of the supported forms is

> select **as** label **for** value **in** array

- select is what the value of the model should be when that item is selected
- label is the text to display

We've combined that with the `(key, value)` grouping, which you can use to get access to the key in the object (or in this case, index in the array).

**Edit**: I'm seeing the same issue you're seeing.  A comment on the angular docs recommends this approach instead:

```
<select ng-model="index" ng-options="items.indexOf(item) as item for item in items">
```

Which IMO is not quite as clean, but seems to work.

Comment: I get no initial selection with this method even though `index = 1`. When monitoring the value I found that when a selection is made, `index` becomes the index as a string `index = "1"`. Perhaps there is a type mismatch?

Comment: Thanks for the edit, that’s it! Not quite as nice perhaps but it beats cluttering the controller by fair margin.

Comment: @sjmulder keep in mind that `[].indexOf` is not present in IE8 in case you have to support it :(

Comment: Good call, we’ll have to polyfill that.

Comment: Whatever 'items.indexOf(item) as item for item in items' means, it beats the other soln since it gives you 2-way data binding AND populates the drop-down from the model. No need for ng-init